# Pandas DataFrame only prints last row

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to make a simple program that utilizes pandas and a for loop but I can't figure out how to get it to print all rows instead of just the last one. I have tried appending to an empty list but that did not solve the problem. I'm sure theres a simple fix to what I'm doing but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

```
import pandas as pd
stocks = ['AMZN', 'ZM', 'SQ']
stocksfinal = []
for stock in stocks:
    Growth = 10
    stocksfinal.append(Growth)
    Value = 8
    stocksfinal.append(Value)
    Discount = 2
    stocksfinal.append(Discount)
    stocksfinal.append(stock)
    data = {
        'Stock': [stock],
        'Growth':[EPSGrowth],
        'Value': [Value],
        'Discount': [Discount]
            }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

With the output being:

```
Stock   Growth  Value   Discount
 SQ      10       8         2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `data` in every iteration of your `for` loop. Also, I don't understand the purpose of your `stocksfinal` variable.

IIUC, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
stocks = ['AMZN', 'ZM', 'SQ']
data = list()
for stock in stocks:
    data.append({'Stock': stock, 'Growth': 10, 'Value': 8, 'Discount': 2})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

>>> df
  Stock  Growth  Value  Discount
0  AMZN      10      8         2
1    ZM      10      8         2
2    SQ      10      8         2
```